# How to decide how many convolutions e deconvolutions apply to a GAN?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to understand how the adversarial generative network works: I found an example in the book by François Chollet (Deep learning with Python) in which there is an example of a GAN he uses CIFAR10 dataset, using the 'frog' class which contains 32x32 RGB images.

I can't understand why:

- In (1) the input is transformed into 16 × 16 128-channel (why 128-channel?) feature map
- In (2) when a convolution is performed, with which filter? It is not specified

Next, run another Conv2DTranspose and then another 3 Conv2d. Why?!

At the end, I have a 32 × 32 1-channel feature map.

```
from keras import layers
import numpy as np
latent_dim = 32
height = 32
width = 32
channels = 3

generator_input = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))

(1)
x = layers.Dense(128 * 16 * 16)(generator_input)
x = layers.LeakyReLU()(x)
x = layers.Reshape((16, 16, 128))(x)

(2)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, 5, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU()(x)

x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, 4, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU()(x)

x = layers.Conv2D(256, 5, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU()(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, 5, padding='same')(x)
x = layers.LeakyReLU()(x)

x = layers.Conv2D(channels, 7, activation='tanh', padding='same')(x)
generator = keras.models.Model(generator_input, x)
generator.summary()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 
It's an arbitrary choice, you could have chosen any number of channels for the Dense layer.

16x16 is picked since a stride of 2 is set to the `Conv2DTranspose` and you want to upsample your width and height to get an output of 32x32.

Strides are used to influence output size of convolution layers. In normal convolutions, outputs are downsampled by the same factor as strides, where in transposed convolutions they are upsampled by the same factor as strides.

For instance, you could change your first layer output to 8x8x128 and then use a stride of 4 in your `Conv2DTranspose`, this way you would get the same result in terms of dimensionality.

Also keep in mind that, as stated by François Chollet in his book, when using strided transposed convolutions, in order to avoid checkerboard artifacts caused by unequal coverage of the pixel space, kernel size should be divisible by its number of strides.

2) The first argument you set in `Conv2D` or `Conv2DTranspose` is the number of filters generated by a convolution layer.

As said before, the strided `Conv2DTranspose` is used exactly to upsample width and height by a factor equal to the number of strides.

The other 3 `Conv2D` are also arbitrary, you should determine them by experimentation and fine tuning your model.

Answer (score 0):

for 1) i do not think there is a reason for the number of dense nodes used (128x16x16), however the 16x16 is set because you only have 1 layer to up sample 16x16 to 32x32.

for 2) the first argument `256` used to instantiate [`Conv2D`](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) defines the number of filters.

In regards to your last question `Next, run another Conv2DTranspose and then another 3 Conv2d. Why?!`  I would recommend try increasing/decreasing the number of layers to get a feel on how the model behaves with those changes (performing better or not), this is part of the "[hyper-parameter tuning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5533)" process when building a neural net.

Hope the above helps.